# Updating Windows Service dll's

Tags: c#, windows-services, inno-setup

I have a windows service that handles upgrading our client machines, we'll call it the upgrade service. This includes updating the main application and various other services.

When a client upgrades currently, this upgrade service, is deleted from the windows services and re-created with the new content for that particular release.

Currently, this service **NEEDS** to run under a domain user which has access to network locations for various reasons.

So my question is, ***how can I keep track of the domain user and password for this service***? So that when replacing all the dll's for it I don't need to prompt the administrator doing the upgrade for the same domain user and password.

If there isn't a way to do this, I know how to prompt the user through inno-setup for the domain user and password. I also, know how to install the service using the command line with a particular user/password combo.

Comment: What changes do you need to make to the service?  Could you use ChangeServiceConfig rather than deleting and recreating it?  (Note also that you can replace the service executable and other files without deleting the service itself.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston there are minimal functional changes that happen from time to time. Those are the main changes. But, if we can just replace all the files and everything stays the same, I think that's what would be easiest it seems like.

Comment: Just stop the service, replace the files, and restart the service. You do not need to re-create it.

Comment: See [Inno Setup - properly stop service before file copy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21390996/850848)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Followed advice in the comment sections of the question, I just stopped the service, deleted all the files, and dropped in the new files. I was able to restart the service then with no problems.